# Glassfish/Payara: can not create connection pool - There is no property isIsolationLevelGuaranteed in entity

Tags: mysql, glassfish, datasource, payara

I am using Payara 4.1.1 Full edition. (I tried both 4.1.1.171 and 4.1.1.164)
I want to create Mysql connection pool. (Tried both 5.1.39 and 6.0.6)
This is the example script that I use to create a connection pool (line breaks for improving readability):

```
asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool 
--datasourceclassname com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource 
--restype javax.sql.DataSource 
--property user=username:password=password:DatabaseName=testDB:ServerName=localhost:port=3306 testDBPool
```

But I get that error:

```
remote failure: JDBC connection pool testDBPool creation failed.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HV000039: Invalid property path. 
There is no property isIsolationLevelGuaranteed in entity org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool.
Command create-jdbc-connection-pool failed.
```

I tried the exact same script on Glassfish 4.1.1 and I get the same error.
But when I try this on Glassfish 4.0, it works properly.

How can I create a mysql connection pool on Payara/Glassfish 4.1.1? (I tried Admin Console but I get the same error.)

Comment: You should add the actual Payara build version you're using (it could be quite important, current is 171) and the version of the mysql jdbc connector.

Comment: ok, edited now.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem before. For this you need to add two properties as JVM Options.

```
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.region=US
```

I have also told you [here](http://ofarukkurt.blogspot.com.tr/2017/08/payara-server-hv000039-invalid-property.html)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with GlassFish 4.1.1:

```
asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool 
--datasourceclassname com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource 
--restype javax.sql.DataSource
--description "Connection pool for MySQL"
--isconnectvalidatereq=true
--validationmethod=table
--validationtable=DUAL
--property user=ghi-java:password="yourpassword":databaseName=dbname:serverName=localhost:port=3306:url="jdbc\:mysql\://\:3306/dbname" ghiDBPool
```

and then:

```
asadmin create-jdbc-resource --connectionpoolid ghiDBPool jdbc/ghiDbConnector.
```

Be sure to copy the mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar in domain-dir/lib and restart the server.